# Integration of $x^3 \tan^{-1}(x)$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having problem with this question. How would one integrate $$\int x^3\tan^{-1}x\,dx\text{ ?}$$
After trying too much I got stuck at this point. How would one integrate $$\int \frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\,dx\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Do you mean the integral of $x^3 \tan^{-1} x$?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I'm asking :)

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. Are you familiar with [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)? Apply the algorithm to get:

$$
\frac{x^4}{1+x^2} = x^2 + \frac{1}{1+x^2} -1
$$

This should be easy to integrate.

Comment: I think it's called Remainder theorem. Is it that?

Comment: @SyedSahl The [polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) is an application of polynomial long division.

Comment: Thank you. I just got it. It's really amazing to be here.

Comment: @SyedSahl You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You've done the hardest part. Now, the problem isn't so much about "calculus"; you simply need to recall what you've learned in algebra:

$(1)$ Divide the numerator of the integrand: $\,{x^4}\,$ by its denominator, $\,{1+x^2}\,$ using [***polynomial long division ***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example), (linked to serve as a reference).

This will give you:
$$\int \frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int (x^2 + \frac{1}{1+x^2} -1)\,dx=\;\;?$$

---

Alternatively: Notice also that $$\int \frac{x^4}{x^2 + 1}\,dx= \int \frac{[(x^4 - 1) + 1]}{x^2 + 1}\,dx$$
$$= \int \frac{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) + 1}{x^2 + 1} \,dx = \int x^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}\,dx$$

I trust you can take it from here?

Comment: "Addition by zero" is also a helpful trick here: $$ \frac{x^4}{1 + x^2} = \frac{x^4 + x^2 - x^2}{1 + x^2} = \frac{x^4 + x^2}{1 + x^2} - \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} = \frac{x^2(1 + x^2)}{1 + x^2} = x^2 - \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$$ The same trick gives: $$ \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} = \frac{x^2 + 1 - 1}{1 + x^2} = \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{1 + x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2} $$  Hence: $$\frac{x^4}{1 + x^2} = x^2 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) $$

Comment: @JavaMan: Yes...indeed!

Comment: @JavaMan Even easier: $x^4-1+1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)+1$.

Comment: @Artem: Your way is shorter, but I try to invoke as little creativity as possible (so as to maximize the chance that the OP remembers the trick).